# OpenVPN connects but doesn't access any sites on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, openvpn

I run my own VPS/OpenVPN server, and everything is configured correctly. I can connect on openSUSE (KDE version) and Ubuntu 13.04, but it doesn't work in Ubuntu 12.04. It connects but doesn't access any sites. I configured it exactly as I did in Ubuntu 13.04.

Additional info:

I installed `openvpn, network-manager-openvpn and network-manager-openvpn-gnome`. Setup the connection with user.crt, ca.crt and user.key (it doesn't have user or password), and activated LZO (exactly how I did in Ubuntu 13.04).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I just found the solution.

There's a catch in Ubuntu 12.04.

To to make it work go to IPv4 Settings and change `Method` to: `Automatic (VPN) addresses only`. After that go to `DNS servers` and enter the address of your favorite DNS server. I like OpenDNS, so the addresses will be: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220.

Comment: I think you mean `Automatic (DHCP) addresses only`.

Comment: No, it's really "Automatic (VPN) addresses only". http://i.stack.imgur.com/X6tTA.png